# Python Simple Grade Book Printing Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with a python file to make a simple Grade Book print properly. I've gotten it to print but its not doing exactly what I need it to. The print results look like this,

`{'Fred': '99', 'Fred2': '99', ...}`

Ideally I'd like it to print just the name and grade next to each other, on a new line for each name / grade. Something like this:

`"Name: Fred | Grade: 99"`

I have to use a list / dictionary and need the while loop

Here is the best solution I have tried thus far:

```
student_grades = {}

entries = input('Would you like to enter a students name and grade? (Y/N): ')
entries = entries.lower()

while entries == "y":
    name = input('Enter a students name: ')
    grade = input('Enter the student\'s grade: ')
    #Put in dictionary
    student_grades[name] = grade
    #Print
    print(student_grades)
    entries = input('Would you like to enter a students name and grade? (Y/N)')
    entries = entries.lower()

else:
    names = list(student_grades.keys())
    grades = list(student_grades.values())
    print()
    print('     Grade Book     ')
    print('--------------------')
    print(student_grades)
```

Comment: I figured it out now, thanks for anyone who answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for student,grade in student_grades.iteritems():
    print "Name:%s, Grade:%s"%(student,grade)
```

Comment: Thank you I was able to implement this and it works very well!

Answer (score 0):

This is the Final Working code for anyone who may need it in the future! Thanks to all who helped!

```
student_grades = {}
entries = input('Would you like to enter a students name and grade? (Y/N): ')
entries = entries.lower()

while entries == "y":
    name = input('Enter a students name: ')
    grade = input('Enter the student\'s grade: ')
    #Put in dictionary
    student_grades[name] = grade
    #Print
    print(student_grades)
    entries = input('Would you like to enter a students name and grade? (Y/N): ')
    entries = entries.lower()

else:
    names = list(student_grades.keys())
    grades = list(student_grades.values())
    print()
    print('     Grade Book     ')
    print('--------------------')
    print()
    for name in student_grades:
        print("Name: "+name+"   "+"Grade: "+student_grades[name])
```